# Create a SIMPLE ASP.NET WebForms app with role-based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've been looking into the two major options for user authentication in ASP.NET and after skimming over a few articles I am absolutely baffled. The last time I dabbled in ASP.NET, the .NET framework was only at v.2.0 which used the Membership system. I can't even really remember how that worked, let alone wrap my head around all this new Entity Framework and Identity stuff.

I like the sound of being able to use external logins (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) and roles, but seriously, why is this crap so damn complicated?! I thought ASP.NET was supposed to make a developer's life **easier**, but just learning how to use it seems like it will take me a week! I'm already behind schedule (this is for a uni project) and my supervisor is getting PO'ed at how long I'm taking to produce no results.

I just want a **simple, easy-to-learn-and-use** methodology for creating the following:

1. A custom database schema with lots of extra user columns (survey questions that they have to answer) and **maybe** a model to go with it, although I'd be just as happy to use raw SQL (that seems to be easier to me!).
2. A registration page that automatically hashes the entered password (preferably with 1000 iterations of PBKDF2, a 32-byte salt and whatever hash function you would recommend for strong security) and redirects to a customised "members" view of Default.aspx on successful registration, or posts back to itself and displays errors if any (depending upon custom validation logic).
3. A login page that also redirects to the same customised Default.aspx and has the usual "Remember Me" checkbox.
4. An "admin" role and "user" role, with registration adding to the users role. A single admin user will be created manually, but they will sign in through the same login form, then be presented with an admin page where they can view/delete users and all their info.

I currently have 1. and 2. implemented with nothing but HTML, CSS, jQuery and SQL, then I started on the login page and realised ASP.NET could probably do a lot of this for me. But how??

Maybe I haven't looked hard enough, or I'm too tired and overworked to fully take in what I've read, but I just want a **simple, concise** solution that covers all of these bases **in one place!** Scouring Google is getting me nowhere as it seems I have to read 5 different 2,000 word articles just to understand all of this stuff!

Anyone that can help me out will become my new god!

Comment: You don't have a specific question here.

Comment: My numbered points are pretty specific...and my question is how to implement those as quickly and easily as possible.

Comment: Your numbered points are a list of requirements. Like you'd had to a contractor, and paid a bunch of money to get it done. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We're here for solving specific programming problems.

Comment: I don't expect you guys to write the entire code for me...just a few snippets that demonstrate the core functionality would be awesome. And opinions on whether to use Membership or Identity for this, and whether Entity Framework is needed (external logins would be a nice but unnecessary feature).

Comment: Look up **Forms Authentication** and **Memebership**. If you're not Windows authenticating, this is an option. There are pre-built controls for logging in/out, and you can roll your own membership provider based on your database.

Comment: Just note rolling your own code will take **considerably** longer than an off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: Asking opinion based questions isn't allowed. And you're still asking us to just write the code for you. We're not here for that. We're here to solve specific problem with your code. Anyways, a lot of what you're asking about is done for you in a new VS 2013 app. Have you tried just creating a new app based on the template? Seems like that does what you're asking for.

Comment: @Tim That's what I was afraid of...maybe a Python-based solution would be easier. Thanks :-)

Comment: @mason I'm sorry I don't want to be a help vampire but I just don't have time to figure this all out. Yes I tried the default template but couldn't figure out how to make it work with my DB. Never mind I'm going to scrap the whole ASP.NET idea. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: If you don't have time to figure it out, then you should *pay* someone to do it for you, rather than asking SO to write your code for you.

Comment: OK, I apologised and said forget it...what part of that don't you understand? And paying someone to do a uni project for you is called plagiarism...getting a bit of help is OK as long as you tell your teacher that you did. And just to be perfectly clear: I never asked for any code, you just (understandably) assumed that's what I wanted, and I said some minor snippets would be awesome, if someone is willing to give them. You obviously aren't that kind of person, but a lot of people on here are. I mainly wanted opinions, but if that's also against the rules, I'll leave you all alone from now on.

Comment: @Kenny83 There's a lot to it - once you move away from Windows authentication, getting it right is a LOT of work. (It's easier than it was in the classic ASP days but still a lot of work)

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate :-) LOL @ ASP, I have heard people talking about still having nightmares about it. ASP.NET doesn't seem to be much better atm but given a good night's sleep and a solid day of reading perhaps I would change my mind ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After reading tons more information about this stuff and spending the last 8 hours on it, I've finally managed to roll my own custom identity provider and DB. As Tim suggested to me, this was a hell of a lot harder than just using the default provider and DB but I'm **almost** completely satisfied now. If I could just figure out how to name the created tables correctly I would be 100% happy with this solution.

For anyone that comes across this post in the future because they have the same question, the basic steps are:

1. Use [JetBrains DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (or any other disassembler) to disassemble `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll` and copy the code for `IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>` into your own custom class.
2. Tweak the columns and methods however you want (I dropped the `PhoneNumberConfirmed` and `TwoFactorEnabled` properties, then added the ones I wanted for my custom columns).
3. Write a custom `<YourDbContextTypeName> : DbContext` class that basically looks like this:

   ```
   public class YourDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public IDbSet<IdentityRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
       public IDbSet<IdentityUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
       public IDbSet<IdentityUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
       public IDbSet<IdentityUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
       public IDbSet<FitAndStrongUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

       public YourDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
           modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
           modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
       }
   }
   ```
4. Copy and paste [Imran Baloch's custom `IUserStore`, `IUserPasswordStore` and `IUserSecurityStampStore`](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity) classes into your own files.
5. Don't forget to give Imran due credit in your documentation, and leave a nice comment on his blog telling him how much his code helped you! I wouldn't object to being mentioned either, but I'm not posting this for the credit...I'm posting it in the hope that some poor sap will find it useful and won't have to waste a whole day like I did!

Given that I've done all the debugging for you, this should only take you a couple of hours, if that. If you're happy to leave `PhoneNumberConfirmed` and `TwoFactorEnabled` in your users table, you can just extend `IdentityUser` and `IdentityDbContext` instead and that should take less than an hour. Just don't forget to pass your custom `IdentityDbContext` instance into your `UserStore`'s constructor (that little doozy took me 2 hours to figure out)!

Now would that have been so hard for someone to tell me yesterday?! :P